# Run celery app in django docker container

Tags: django, linux, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Django project which uses docker and docker-compose, and I want to use Celery within the Django project.
I have followed Celery docs to create an app, a task and connect it with RabbitMQ broker.

This is my celery.py file, in the same dir as the settings.py file:

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")

backtest_app = Celery("backtest_app")

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
backtest_app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
backtest_app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Also I have set the Celery app config in the settings.py file:

```
# CELERY config
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://rabbitmq:5672"
CELERY_BROKER_USER = "user"
CELERY_BROKER_PASSWORD = "pass"
CELERY_BACKEND = "rpc://"
CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 100
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "backtest_queue"
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "backtest_exchange"
CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = "backtest_queue"
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "UTC"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "django-db"
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = "django-cache"
```

Now, I have this code in the Dockerfile of the backend:

```
FROM python:3.10.8-alpine

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc:
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Instal pip
# RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
#     apk add py-pip
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
    && apk add gcc python3-dev musl-dev build-base gcc wget
# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# TA-Lib
RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN pip install TA-Lib==0.4.25
RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

RUN mkdir /worker
WORKDIR /worker
COPY . .

# Create a directory for logs
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs
# # Installation der erforderlichen Python-Pakete
# RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

I also, have this code as the backend service in the docker-compose file:

```
webapp_backend:
    build: ./webapp_backend
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate --noinput && gunicorn proj.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:80"
    volumes:
      - backend_data:/webapp_backend/media/
    env_file:
      - webapp_backend/.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
```

Now, I want to run the Celery app in the backend container, so that it can catch the tasks. but putting it inside the 'command' in the webapp_backend service, does not initiate the worker, as the terminal is already busy with running the `gunicorn proj.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:80` command.

One way that I can think of (but I cannot make it happen) is to create two separate terminals in the webapp_backend container, two run the `celery -A proj worker --loglevel=info` command there. If this solution is valid, please help me achieve this. But if it is not a valid solution, suggest one.

Also I need to mention that ChatGPT has given me a way, and although it works but it is not a good one.
It suggested to have another service, named 'celery_worker' as below:

```
  # celery_worker:
  #   build: ./webapp_backend
  #   command: celery -A proj worker --loglevel=info
  #   volumes:
  #     - backend_data:/webapp_backend/media/
  #   env_file:
  #     - webapp_backend/.env
  #   depends_on:
  #     - webapp_backend
```

But as you see, this builds another container exactly like the webapp_backend, and copies all the code of the project to this new container, just to initiate the worker, which if I understand correctly and it actually does copy the whole container, then it is not at all a good approach to do it this way. Although it works and the tasks are done, but I am looking for another method.

Answer (score 1):

Celery program manages processes itself and is easier to setup through a separate command. Generally, only a single program is run inside a docker container that manages all the unix processes for better signal handling mechanisms during scaling. For example, gunicorn in pre-fork mode spawns child processes, which it controls through the master process(PID 1).

Celery should be run in a separate process and preferably in a separate container for signal handling mechanism to avoid unexpected issues as ChatGPT suggested. But you can architect your application, such that unnecessary heavy libraries won't get imported in django/celery applications and use [signatures](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#signatures) to pass functions as strings.

You can also run multiple processes in a single container with one process taking PID 1 and others running in the [background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/run-a-command-without-making-me-wait) to save on resources although it's not a recommended approach. These libraries come with in-built POSIX signal handling mechanisms and it's important to send these signals to those applications.

Alternatively, you can see if [apscheduler](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler) fits your need. It manages communication using your OS instead of an external broker and cannot be auto scaled seperately.

Comment: What about supervisord.conf file? I am using that now, but I am not sure if it is the perfect solution.